# how to get value after colon with sed

Tags: linux, sed, curl

I have these:

```
variable="call_type: I alert_id: 2334 server: serverA run_as: sub_ap: FRUIT...."
```

I need only one command to get value of the variables.
I try with these:

```
callType=$(echo $variable | sed 's/call_type: \(.*\) alert_id.*/\1/')
```

It's OK, it gives me value **I**.

But if some field doesn't have value like **run_as:**

```
runAs=$(echo $* | sed 's/.* run_as: \(.*\) sub_ap.*/\1/')
```

It gives me all the line.

How could I do that?I need only one statement line that can use in all cases.
Thanks and sorry for my English!

Comment: Is the code supposed to return `I`, `2334`, `serverA`, a blank string, and `FRUIT`?

Comment: We need a clear example of exactly what you would like to extract before we will be able to help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your `sed` code assumes there's a space just after `run_as:` and *another* space just before `sub_ap:`. The value you want to get is between the two spaces.

But in your data there's exactly one space between `run_as:` and `sub_ap:`

> ```
> call_type: I alert_id: 2334 server: serverA run_as: sub_ap: FRUIT....
> ```

And even if there were two spaces, in many shells `echo $variable` would turn them into one space because of the [lack of quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618) and of what `echo` does when it receives multiple arguments:

> The `echo` utility arguments shall be separated by *single* <space> characters and a <newline> character shall follow the last argument.

<sup>([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html); emphasis mine)</sup>

Your troublesome `sed 's…'` matches nothing, replaces nothing, therefore you get the whole line.

The simplest fix is to allow one of the two spaces not to be there:

```
sed 's/.* run_as: \?\(.*\) sub_ap.*/\1/'
```

IMO a format that passes keys and values in one single line is somewhat peculiar; a format that drops a separator after an empty string is rather dumb.

---

Maybe the dumb format is something you're creating on the fly and the original input is not that dumb. Maybe the original input is a single string that does contain two spaces between `run_as:` and `sub_ap:`, and your problem is because of `echo $variable`. Or maybe the original input is not dumb nor peculiar at all. **The usage of `$*` makes me *suspect*** you're trying to process positional parameters that *may* be quite sane. Like these:

`call_type: I`, `alert_id: 2334`, `server: serverA`, `run_as:` , `sub_ap: FRUIT`, …

or like these:

`call_type:`, `I`, `alert_id:`, `2334`, `server:`, `serverA`, `run_as:`,  (empty value), `sub_ap:`, `FRUIT`, …

And *maybe* you don't know how to iterate over positional parameters, so you used `echo $*` to get a single string you kinda know how to process with `sed`.

[Do not use unquoted `$*`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41595/108618). [Consider not using `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618). If you *really* need to concatenate positional parameters then use `printf '%s\n' "$*"`, not `echo $*`. Your `sed` command should work then. In this particular case even `echo "$*"` would help.

But if I'm right and what you're trying to process comes from multiple positional parameters that can pass empty values in a sane way then you should definitely concentrate on parsing the parameters one by one (or pair by pair) instead of building anything that involves `$*`.